# Find minimum for histogram

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk

I have a simple histogram like this:

```
1.5 1.34
2.5 5.23
3.5 7.34
4.5 4.23
5.5 3.23
6.5 2.22
7.5 1.94
8.5 5.43
9.5 9.13
```

I need to find the minimum vale of the second column which is after the first maximum vale, and print out the corresponding value of the first colum. so I should get this output:

```
7.5 1.94
```

Could anyone suggest a nice solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'NR == 1 {mx=$1;my=$2}
   $2 < my {mx=$1;my=$2}
   $2 == my && $1 > mx {mx=$1;my=$2}
   END{print mx " " my}'
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about floating point values. I have updated the post for this requirement...

Comment: It seams that I did not understand the problem correctly.  New solution coming.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR == 1 {my=$2;max_found=0}
  !max_found && $2 > my {my=$2}
  !max_found && $2 < my {mx=$1;my=$2;max_found=1}
  max_found && $2 < my {mx=$1;my=$2}
  max_found && $2 > my {exit}
  END{print mx " " my}'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sort -k2,2n file | awk 'NR<2{max=$1} FNR<NR && $2>=max{print;exit}' file -
```

or this:

```
 awk 'NR<2{max=$1}$2<max{next}min==0{line=$0;min=$2}$2<min{line=$0;min=$2}END{print line}' file
```